# How to sumif in arrayformula in different ranges

Tags: google-sheets, sum, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to use `sumif` in an array formula to count the number in these ranges C:C R:AH, these ranges contains numbers from 1 to 10 and "above 10" which I consider it as 11 but I can't name it 11 in the sheet

I tried this equation but it didn't work `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Count of errors",IF(LEN(A:A),IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFS(ISNUMBER({C:AH}), "♦",{C:C,R:AH}="Above 10","♦" )),, 999^99)), "♦"))="♦", 1, 0), )))`

I want the equation to sum the numbers in the range C:C,R:AH as in row 1 in the sample data the columns contain Above 10, 4 & 2 so I need the equation to display 17 and so on

Sample Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SksZv0h82j5oEZBj2AN5anDFr80AYNR5ettSwkpUKys/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so the range is **`{C:C, R:AH}`** or **`{C:AH}`** ? because the 2nd row would be 6 not 17 coz "Above 10" is in N column - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E6sm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is simple `MMULT` with `SUBSTITUTE` for "Above 10":

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Count of errors"; IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 MMULT(SUBSTITUTE(C2:AH, "Above 10", 11)*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:AH)^0)), )})
```

[image: 0]

---

for **{C2:C, R2:AH}** use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Count of errors"; IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 MMULT(SUBSTITUTE({C2:C, R2:AH}, "Above 10", 11)*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Q2:AH)^0)), )})
```